# Isn't it possible to debug remotely with only forwarding the GDB server port?

Tags: arm, stm32, gdbserver

I have a debugger connected to a Linux box as follows:

```
[Debugger] <- usb -> [Machine A] <- tcp -> [Rendezvous server] <- tcp -> [Laptop]
```

I can start `st-util` on `Machine A`, forward the `:4242` port to the `Laptop` and connect it as follows:

```
laptop$ arm-none-eabi-gdb target extended-remote localhost:4242
```

Connection is successful and I can flash the microcontroller.

However, when I need to debug, `gdb` keeps saying `value has been optimized out`.

What is wrong with my setup? Isn't forwarding the server port enough for remote debugging?

## Edit

I didn't think this is a compiler optimization issue because it wasn't present while I was debugging with direct connection. However, I installed the necessary toolchain on the `Machine A` but the result is the same. Here is the `make` output:

```
/home/ceremcem/embedded/gcc/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin//arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F407xx -ICore/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32
F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -Imodbus_lib -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wextra -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/main.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/main.lst Core/Src/main.c -o build/main.o
```

As we can see, the `-Og` option is used and [it is suitable for debugging purposes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> Optimize debugging experience. -Og should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience. It is a better choice than -O0 for producing debuggable code because some compiler passes that collect debug information are disabled at -O0.
>
> Like -O0, -Og completely disables a number of optimization passes so that individual options controlling them have no effect. Otherwise -Og enables all -O1 optimization flags except for those that may interfere with debugging: (...)

## Solution

(moved to answer)

Comment: dont think it has anything to do with gdb or your setup looks like your compiler optimized out the variable, need to build without optimizations or build with debug that may also reduce optimizations allowing for you to "see" the variable.

Comment: if you prepare a mimimal example I think you will see for yourself what is going on...

Comment: I was preparing to answer your point and you were right, it was all about the optimization flag.

Answer (score -1):

Despite the documentation and my previous experience, I used `-O0` instead of `-Og` as the build option and voila, the debugger just printed what I expected.

Comment: -Og does some optimizations. So it is quite obvious that disabling them you prevent the variable from being optimized out.

Comment: It's still interesting that I had been using `-Og` since the beginning of the project (months) and it had never done such an optimization before.